# Significance of $\operatorname{mean}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(1:(x-1)}{x}}\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

In finance, it's common to scale by the sqrt of time. I came upon a relation that I don't understand why it asymptotically goes to about 0.6667.

Some R code:

```
b <- data.frame(n = NA, mean_sqrt = NA)

for (x in seq(from = 10, to = 5000, by = 10)){
  b[x/10,1] <- x
  b[x/10,2] <- mean(sqrt(1:(x-1)/x))

}

plot(b, type = 'l')
```

The gist is if we take the mean sqrt of 1/10 to 9/10 it will equate to about 0.678. If we do the same for 1/20 to 19/20 it will equate to about 0.673, and so on asymtotically to about 0.6667. Why? Is there any significance in this kind of series? And what exactly is this value that we are asymptotically aproaching?

Answer (score 1):

We can prove it with a [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). For large $n$, $$\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}\sim\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\int_0^1x^{1/2}dx=\left[\frac23x^{3/2}\right]_0^1=\frac23.$$

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick proof!

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as @J.G., consider
$$y_n=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{i}{n}}=\frac{H_{n-1}^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}{(n-1) \sqrt n}$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers. Using their asymptotics
$$y_n=\frac 23+\frac 1{6n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$$ which confirms your observation that the limit is approached by above.